# Rotating a vehicle to match a 2D slope

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, movement, collider

I have a vehicle that needs to move on a randomly generated terrain and handle slopes. I'm not using wheels, but instead moving the vehicle with velocity. The ideal case would be if I can make the vehicle rotate according to the terrain edges and move smoothly as shown here:

[image: Diagram of a green square sliding down a black terrain, rotating to match the ground]

How can I accomplish this? Launching raycast from the bottom left angle and calculating the distance from the ground, then rotating according to that?

Comment: Your raycast proposal sounds promising, [and has been used effectively by other games](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/71609/39518). Have you tried implementing this solution? Did you run into any specific difficulty making it work the way you wanted it to?

Comment: Food for thought: [How Did They Do That - Mario Galaxy's Gravity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vALtyrp87mI).