# Rotate character

Tags: unity, physics, rotation

I want my player character (the feet ) to stick to the platform (like in the photo) rather than falling or following the physics. I want it to move like a spider but I am stuck.

With the help of [this site](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AdamWinkels/20140220/211306/DevLog_7_Learning_How_to_Walk.php), I was able to get to find the solution of my problem to get the following result.[image]

Now I have this code and I cannot get it working because of my less understanding of the whole process. The script is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerRays : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float distance;
    public RaycastHit2D leftHitInfo;
    public RaycastHit2D rightHitInfo;

    public LayerMask layer;
    public float offset;
    public bool rayCastThrown;

    public float maxRotationDegrees;
    public float positionOffsetY;

    bool doubleRaycasts (Vector2 rightOffSet, Vector2 leftOffSet) {
        
        

        return Physics2D.Raycast (rightOffSet, Vector2.down,  distance, layer) && Physics2D.Raycast (leftOffSet, Vector2.down,  distance, layer);
    }

    void PositionOnTerrain () {
        
        Vector3 averageNormal = ( leftHitInfo.normal + rightHitInfo.normal ) / 2;
        Vector3 averagePoint = (leftHitInfo.point + rightHitInfo.point) / 2;

        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector2.up, averageNormal);
        Quaternion finalRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards (transform.rotation, targetRotation, maxRotationDegrees);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,0, finalRotation.eulerAngles.z);

        transform.position =averagePoint + transform.up * positionOffsetY;

        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, -averageNormal,  Color.red);

    }
    
    void Update () {
        Vector2 leftOffSet = new Vector2 (transform.position.x - offset, transform.position.y);
        Vector2 rightOffSet = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + offset, transform.position.y);
        
        leftHitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast (leftOffSet, Vector2.down);
        rightHitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast (rightOffSet, Vector2.down);
        rayCastThrown = doubleRaycasts (rightOffSet, leftOffSet);
        Debug.DrawRay (leftOffSet , Vector2.down * distance, Color.yellow);
        Debug.DrawRay (rightOffSet, Vector2.down * distance, Color.cyan);

        PositionOnTerrain ();
    

    }


}
```

I cannot get it to working at all and while it seems to be working sometime and I can only see the red line working sometime (very rarely). I cannot pin point the problem as I see no result at all. I cannot wrap my head around the part of Quaternions and after that as given in the above link.

Comment: You may be interested in [How do I make a character capable of walking on walls](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/71585/39518) — similar techniques should be applicable here.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks. it seems like it would work on slopes and come across cliff but how would I make it work in perfect righ angled barrier? Or maybe I don't get it.

Comment: That's answered in the paragraphs of my answer that are second and third from the end.

Comment: @DMGregory Whats TerrainMovementRayProperties in the code? Whats maxrotation and position off setY?

Comment: I recommend editing your question to explain what you're trying to do in your game (you deleted that part), explain what the code you're using is doing, and how it differs from what you need it to do.

Comment: @DMGregory I changed it. The script is not doing anything at all and it gives weird motions max rotation degree and position offset Y (starts moving up and down) which I dont know what it does. I mistake some of the rotations done by rigidbody2D before. Please help :(

Comment: Whats TerrainMovementRayProperties in the code? I cannot just multiply two vector3 or if its float, I cannot add it, right? Is the origin of the ray complex because it should know the direction of the player? @DMGregory

Comment: Why are you tagging me in a question about code I did not write or suggest that you copy-paste into your project?

Comment: I am really sorry. I just did it because no one is answering or leaving comment. But I have lot of sub questions in this questions and I have tried everything I can. I will make questions for each sub questions :)