# Camera movement automatically tracking a tool over a surface

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I need to create camera movement tracking the clipper hair like this:

[image: Animated gif of hair being buzzed in a barbershop game]

I already have a script for the movement of the tool.

- I'm using Snapping Player to the Surface of an Object of this pos [How could I constrain player movement to the surface of a 3D object using Unity?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89693/how-could-i-constrain-player-movement-to-the-surface-of-a-3d-object-using-unity)

  ```
    private void UpdatePlayerTransform(Vector3 movementDirection){
    if (GetRaycastDownAtNewPosition(movementDirection, out hitInfo)){
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
        finalRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, float.PositiveInfinity);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, finalRotation, Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, hitInfo.point + hitInfo.normal * .08f, Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
        }
    }

    private bool GetRaycastDownAtNewPosition(Vector3 movementDirection, out RaycastHit hitInfo)
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position + movementDirection * Speed, -transform.up);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 1f, WorldLayerMask))
            return true;

        return false;
  ```

}

- I'm find move director

  ```
    void FindMovementDirVector(){
    try
    {
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(hitInfo.normal, Vector3.up);
        float angleWithForward = Vector3.Angle(hitInfo.normal, Vector3.forward);
        if (angleWithForward < 90 && angle < 60)
        {
            caseName = "Case 1";

            if (angleWithForward > 30)
                localForwardDir = Vector3.Lerp(localForwardDir, Vector3.Cross(hitInfo.normal, -Camera.main.transform.right), Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
            else
                localForwardDir = Vector3.Lerp(localForwardDir, Vector3.Cross(hitInfo.normal, LocalRightDir), Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);

            LocalRightDir = Vector3.Lerp(LocalRightDir, Vector3.Cross(-localForwardDir, hitInfo.normal), Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
        }
        else
        {
            caseName = "Case 2";
            Vector3 to = new Vector3(hitInfo.normal.x + hitInfo.point.x, hitInfo.point.y, hitInfo.normal.z + hitInfo.point.z);
            if (angleWithForward > 35)
                LocalRightDir = Vector3.Lerp(LocalRightDir, Vector3.Cross(to, Vector3.up), Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
            else
                LocalRightDir = Vector3.Lerp(LocalRightDir, -Vector3.Cross(to, Vector3.up), Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
            localForwardDir = Vector3.Lerp(localForwardDir, -Vector3.Cross(hitInfo.normal, LocalRightDir), Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
        }
    }
    catch { }
    }
  ```

  - Input script

    ```
      private void TouchInput(){
      if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
      {
          pointer_x = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
          pointer_y = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;

          if (pointer_x > 0)
              movementDirection += LocalRightDir * pointer_x;
          else if (pointer_x < 0)
              movementDirection -= LocalRightDir * Mathf.Abs(pointer_x);

          if (pointer_y > 0)
              movementDirection += localForwardDir * pointer_y;
          else if (pointer_y < 0)
              movementDirection -= localForwardDir * Mathf.Abs(pointer_y);
      }}
    ```

Comment: Like what? The user can move it like that? Automatically? Tracking the tool?

Comment: That's a simple orbiting camera. Also, UnityScript is deprecated.

Comment: Hello @Zibelas! sorry for my mistake. I want camera automatically tracking the tool

Comment: Is the tool restricted to the top/back of a head exactly as shown here, or do you have any other scenarios it needs to handle? Be sure to read the tag descriptions too — you probably want an answer in C# unless you're using a decade-old Unity version that still has UnityScript in it.

Comment: I would just influence the cameras rotation by the position of the shaver, how you implement it is up to you

Comment: @Pow Presumably Lưu Anh does not know how to implement it, or they would not have posted this question.

Comment: @DMGregory Hello!!! The tool restricted to the top, back, left and right side. I just wanna some idea to make camera automatically tracking the tool. Thanks you!

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, I was just giving a recommendation, I didn't have time to test it or write an answer at the time.

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I would add an empty game object in the middle of the head and have the camera always LookAt() it.
Then place another empty game object, as a child of the clippers, and have your camera always move towards it, probably using Vector3.SmoothDamp() (as it will give a bit of easing to the camera movement).

Danny

Comment: This approach would not achieve the look in the example GIF. The camera doesn't move as far as the clippers. Also, Vector3.SmoothDamp() moves in a straight line, which often isn't desirable for an orbit camera because it won't maintain the same orbit distance.

Comment: Thanks you! I tried. But it doesn't work like that.